# viber top icon is missing

Tags: viber

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wziXb.png)

I am using this one And I can't see viber in the top left menu. I download the new version. And installed. But it is not showing at the top.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wh0d4.png)